# Getting "IntegrityError FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" when i am trying to generate the invoice from booking table

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to generate an invoice from the booking table. I have created a separate table for invoices and declared a foreign key for the booking table and package too. But whenever I try to generate an invoice it gives a Foreign key constraint.

Here is my models file

**models.py**

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    photographer = models.ForeignKey(Photographer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    booking = models.ForeignKey(Booking,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    extra_amt = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    total_amt = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is the view that I created to generate invoice

**views.py**

```
def generate_invoice(request,id):
    photographer = Photographer.objects.get(user=request.user)
    booking = Booking.objects.get(id=id)
    packages = Package.objects.filter(photographer=photographer)

    if request.method == "POST":
        package_get = request.POST.get('package')
        extra_amt = request.POST.get('extra_amt')
        payment_status = request.POST.get('payment_status')

        invoice = Invoice(
            photographer = photographer,
            booking = booking,
            package_id = package_get,
            extra_amt = extra_amt,
            payment_status = payment_status,
        )

        invoice.save()
        messages.success(request,'Invoice generated Successfully')
        return redirect('view_booking')

    
    context = {
        'package':packages,
    }
    return render(request,'customadmin/photographer/generate_invoice.html',context)
```

When I click on submit button to generate url it shows below error on this url

*http://localhost:8000/customadmin/bookings/generate-invoice/5/*

```
IntegrityError at /customadmin/bookings/generate-invoice/5/
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/customadmin/bookings/generate-invoice/5/
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
Exception Location: /home/shreyas/project/mainPhotographer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 416, in execute
Python Executable:  /home/shreyas/project/mainPhotographer/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path:    
['/home/shreyas/project/mainPhotographer/src',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/shreyas/project/mainPhotographer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 23 Dec 2021 06:28:14 +0000
```

Comment: There are 3 FK-s on your model, and at least one of them is empty or has invalid value. As it does not fail on retrieving `photographer` and `booking`, then it must be `package_id`, which comes from POST. Try to debug it to see, what comes in there.

Comment: @Som-1 Thanks. problem solved.